# How can I make my Perl Jabber bot an event-driven program?

Tags: perl, events, xmpp, bots

I'm trying to make a Jabber bot and I am having trouble keeping it running while waiting for messages.  How do I get my script to continuously run?  I have tried calling a subroutine that has a while loop that I, in theory, have set up to check for any messages and react accordingly but my script isn't behaving that way.

Here is my source: http://pastebin.com/03Habbvh

```
# set jabber bot callbacks
$jabberBot->SetMessageCallBacks(chat=>\&chat);
$jabberBot->SetPresenceCallBacks(available=>\&welcome,unavailable=>\&killBot);
$jabberBot->SetCallBacks(receive=>\&prnt,iq=>\&gotIQ);

$jabberBot->PresenceSend(type=>"available");
$jabberBot->Process(1);

sub welcome
{
    print "Welcome!\n";
    $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$jbrBoss->GetJID(),subject=>"",body=>"Hello There!",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
    &keepItGoing;
}

sub prnt
{
    print $_[1]."\n";
}

#$jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$jbrBoss->GetJID(),subject=>"",body=>"Hello There! Global...",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
#$jabberBot->Process(5);
#&keepItGoing;

sub chat
{
    my ($sessionID,$msg) = @_;
    $dump->pl2xml($msg);
    if($msg->GetType() ne 'get' && $msg->GetType() ne 'set' && $msg->GetType() ne '')
    {
        my $jbrCmd = &trimSpaces($msg->GetBody());
        my $dbQry = $dbh->prepare("SELECT command,acknowledgement FROM commands WHERE message = '".lc($jbrCmd)."'");
        $dbQry->execute();
        if($dbQry->rows() > 0 && $jbrCmd !~ /^insert/si)
        {
            my $ref = $dbQry->fetchrow_hashref();
            $dbQry->finish();
            $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$msg->GetFrom(),subject=>"",body=>$ref->{'acknowledgement'},type=>"chat",priority=>10);
            eval $ref->{'command'};
            &keepItGoing;
        }
        else
        {
            $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$msg->GetFrom(),subject=>"",body=>"I didn't understand you!",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
            $dbQry->finish();
            &keepItGoing;
        }
    }
}

sub gotIQ
{
    print "iq\n";
}

sub trimSpaces
{
    my $string = $_[0];
    $string =~ s/^\s+//; #remove leading spaces
    $string =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces
    return $string;
}

sub keepItGoing
{

    print "keepItGoing!\n";
    my $proc = $jabberBot->Process(1);
    while(defined($proc) && $proc != 1)
    {
        $proc = $jabberBot->Process(1);
    }
}

sub killBot
{
    print "killing\n";
    $jabberBot->MessageSend(to=>$_[0]->GetFrom(),subject=>"",body=>"Logging Out!",type=>"chat",priority=>10);
    $jabberBot->Process(1);
    $jabberBot->Disconnect();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[POE](http://poe.perl.org/) has some pretty good event frameworks. I don't know how good the one for Jabber (POE::Component::Jabber) is, but it's probably worth looking at.

Answer (score 4):

[AnyEvent::XMPP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent-XMPP) is ridiculously comprehensive, and, since it uses [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent), can be run in any event driven application with a supported loop ([AnyEvent's own](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent/lib/AnyEvent/Impl/Perl.pm), [Event](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Event), [EV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/EV), [Tk](http://www.perltk.org/), [Glib/Gtk](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/), even [POE](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POE)).

Comment: I tried using AnyEvent but I ran into trouble during execution. I'll give it another shot, but do you know if it's available for ActivePerl? I ultimately want this to run on a *nix machine but right now I'm developing on windows 7 using eclipse and its perl plugin.

Comment: I tried using the AnyEvent module again and when ever I try to send a message or set the presence of my bot, I get an error saying the object method "push_write" can't be found for AnyEvent::Util::guard and I can't figure out how to fix it.  I think it might be because I'm using a 64-bit version of perl on CentOS 5.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make your example work by doing this:

```
0 while $jabber->Process
```

Having said that, I would strongly recommend using a proper Event handling framework such as AnyEvent (my personal favorite) or POE (the traditional choice).

Comment: that's what my loop uses now but it gets messed up if I get iq packets and message packets.